# Android - web server connectivity and authentification

Tags: php, android, c, security

I need my app to be able communicate with a web server. The problem is I want web server to respond only to requests made from real android phones.

So, is there any way to make sure, that server works only with real phones? It should reject anything else to prevent spamming database from computers or emulators. Is it possible without sms verification?

And how good is socket support in Android? If I want to write server software in C will it be able to communicate with Android based devices? Or I have to use php, or something like that?

Maybe OpenSSL, but still I'm not sure.

Thanks in advance!
PS: sorry for my English

Answer (score 2):

There is no real way for a web server to distinguish a real mobile device from a device that poses as one. Generally, the user-agent header is used to determine the type of client device, the value of which can be overwritten by any client.

Comment: It is really like that, and it is sad. I think I have to write my own protocol. Everything can be overwritten. Are there any other methods? Hardware lock, during the first registration? IMEI? Or it is only possible by sending sms and having user to enter recieved code during registration, to prove that he actually is a real person?

Comment: If it is verification you are after, it is always a good idea to get the user to enter code received on his handset. Sometimes user-initiated verification are better than technical solutions. :)